# How do I tell lxml which charset to use?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm working with html and using lxml to parse it. For testing purposes I have an html document saved as a string in a python file with encoding=utf-8 at the top.

Whenever I try to parse the html using lxml I get weird html encodings if the html does not have the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

This is the code:

```
t = lxml.html.fromstring(page_html)
print lxml.html.tostring(t)
```

If the `page_html` string contains the meta charset above the `tostring()` method returns nicely encoded html (i.e. `’` turns into `&#8217;`). If it does not have it, the results are garbled (i.e. `’` turns into `&#226;&#128;&#153;`)

This encoding happens in the `fromstring` method rather than the `tostring` one so I can't just insert a new meta element in the tree after it is created as by that time it is to late.

The only solution I can think of is to try and modify the original html string and add the meta tag there before creating the tree. This seems kinda klunky though. Isn't there a better way to do it using lxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just need to pass in a custom parser to the `fromstring` method. So this fixes it:

```
parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
t = lxml.html.fromstring(page_html, parser=parser)
print lxml.html.tostring(t)
```